# Dlib was compiled to use SSE41 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine

Tags: python, linux, pip, sse, dlib

I installed Dlib(on Linux) for Python2.7 using : `pip install dlib`

The installation was successful. However, when I enter the Python interactive mode and try to `import dlib` ,

It throws a (warning?) messages saying:

> Dlib was compiled to use SSE41 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.

Is this something related to the hardware? I'm not using a very new machine but everything else works just fine. Is there any other way in which I can install this?

NOTE : I'm using virtualenvs. I tried using anaconda initially, where I was able to install dlib too, but I do not want to use that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SSE 4.1 is a SIMD instruction set extension found in Intel Core i3/i5/i7 and AMD Bulldozer and later. If you have e.g. a Core 2 Duo, it doesn't support it. I don't know the best solution for this on whichever distro you're using, but worst case you can compile dlib from source.

Comment: @thatotherguy Surely this should be an answer? (Makes a change from saying an answer should be a comment!)

Comment: @SiHa It doesn't actually solve the problem

Comment: @saloni - SSE2, SSSE3, SSE4, AVX, AVX2, BMI, BMI2 and friends are CPU features. You can't install them. Older machines, Like Core Solo and Duo, lack them. For newer machines, Intel sells low end processors that only have SSE2, SSSE3 and AESNI. They lack SSE4 and above. OEM's have to request the product from Intel, like an [Atom D2550](https://ark.intel.com/products/65470/Intel-Atom-Processor-D2550-1M-Cache-1_86-GHz). Also see Crypto++ [Pull Request 72](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/pull/172), which avoided a SIGILL crash because AESNI was available but not SSE4.1.

Comment: My machine has Core 2 Duo and Peppermint Linux OS. I understand the issue here. Like @thatotherguy suggested, I guess I'll try compiling dlib from source. That seems to be a time-taking process, though. Will dlib work fine after that(for sure?) ? (Because I'd rather try it on a newer machine and have it work)

Comment: Hi @thatotherguy, I have the same problem like salonitiwari's question and I read your comment that worst case I can compile dlib from source.. since I am new in this field, would you like to give me information about how to  compile dlib from source ?

Comment: @uyhaW I googled "compiling dlib from source" and found [this page](http://dlib.net/compile.html). If you're not used to compiling software from source, it can be tricky.

Comment: @thatotherguy thank you for the information you have given, I will try to read that first