# Centos 7 - Dlib was compiled to use SSE41 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine

Tags: python, centos7, dlib

I am trying to use `dlib` as one of python packages. It is installed successfully but when I open python shel and type `import dlib`.. it says that

```
Dlib was compiled to use SSE41 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.
```

is that a kind of warning ?

but when I check `dlib.__version__`, I still get the result `'19.21.1'`.
So is that okay to ignore that? or is there a way to solve that if that's really an error?
Actually I have been reading this [Dlib was compiled to use SSE41 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348999/dlib-was-compiled-to-use-sse41-instructions-but-these-arent-available-on-your) article and [TensorFlow library was compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these aren't available on your machine. Aborted (core dumped)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950186/tensorflow-library-was-compiled-to-use-sse4-1-instructions-but-these-arent-ava)

and I want to make sure that I need to Upgrade my Machine to a modern build (as it says in this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/53950228/13240914)
and here is some information about cpu:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            15
Model:                 6
Model name:            Common KVM processor
```

also, the result of `flag`:

```
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni cx16 x2apic hypervisor lahf_lm
```

Comment: SSE 4.1 is extremely old. Which CPU are you using? If it doesn't support SSE 4.1 then obviously the DLL can't run if some SSE 4.1 instruction is called

Comment: @phuclv I am using Common KVM processor.. so the one way to solve this problem is  upgrading the machine to a modern build, right ?

Comment: there's no such thing as a "Common KVM processor". There are only 3 x86 manufacturers: Intel, AMD and Via, and the real CPU model is necessary to know what instruction set it supports

Comment: @phuclv I have updated my question, would you like to take a look ?

Comment: it seems you're using a virtual machine and KVM has faked the CPU model. There's no useful information from the above lines. Why don't just get the information from a real physical machine, or post the `flags` in the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: @phuclv I update my question, would you like to give me information about that since I don't really know about this problem

Comment: @phuclv as I read the ```flag``` yea it supports sse2

Comment: yes it's so old that it only supports SSE2. SSE 4.1 is 3 generations after that: SSE3, SSSE3 and SSE4. Either recompile the source code for SSE2, or better buy a new machine

Comment: @phuclv I will make a note about it, thank you very much for your information, that helps me to do the next